universal structures over $\mathcal A_g$
Over the moduli space of curves, $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$ there are several "natural" spaces like the universal curve, the universal Jacobian, the space of stable maps, the universal space of semistable bundles, the universal Quot scheme...
Is there some space of this form over $\mathcal A_g$ apart from the universal abelian variety, its $k$-fold products and the Poincare bundle that

Has some universal object, like a Poincare bundle.

Is proper over $\mathcal A_g$



There certainly exist spaces of maps from abelian varieties to a fixed space (analogous to the space of stable maps) and spaces parameterizing bundles on abelian varieties (analogous to the universal space of semistable bundles). One can also consider the moduli space of pairs of a curve of some genus and degree inside the abelian variety and then any of these types of structure in the curve.

@WillSawin I hope now the question is more clear. As far as I know the space of semi stable bundles on an abelian variety does not have a universal object, since stable =/= semi stable for large $g$

Hilbert schemes are always proper and always have a universal object, so these would be examples.
